# Render an element from multiple dimension array in Twig Opencart

Tags: twig, opencart

I have the following HTML code in a twig view file

```
<input type="text" 
   name="myArray[{{ nthRow }}][description][{{ language.language_id }}][name]"
   value="{{ myArray.description.language_id.name }}" 
   class="form-control" />
```

this is the print_r of the array which is being sent to the twig file

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
    [var1] => safds 
    [var2] => 0 
    [var3] => 1000 
    [description] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => bla bla ) )
   )
)
```

how can I reach the name element of the array??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, it should be like this,

```
<input type="text" 
       name="myArray[{{ nthRow }}][description][{{ language.language_id }}][name]" 
       value="{{ myArray.description[language.language_id].name }}"
       class="form-control" 
/>
```

Comment: you are probably looping the `myArray` somewhere above, am I correct? otherwise, how did you skip the myArray[0]...

Comment: well the value ın the name field doesn't have necessary to be the same as the value in the value field, so I just missed the brackets for language.language_id, when I removed [nthRow] and added brackets, the problem was solved, thanks anyway

Comment: awesome! glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

How about `myArray[nthRow].description[language.language_id].name`

so the twig code may look like this

```html
<input type="text" 
   name="myArray[{{ nthRow }}][description][{{ language.language_id }}][name]"
   value="{{  myArray[nthRow].description[language.language_id].name }}" 
   class="form-control" />
```

Comment: @dimitry
that helped but still something didn't work, there is no need to nthRow in myArray[nthRow]